# Telerik MVC Grid Export to Excel function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What happen here is that the grid has 250000 records. When I try to use kendo build-in grid.saveAsExcel() function. It actually request READ function in the backend, and give parameters 
{ 
sort:
page:1
pageSize:250020
group:
filter:
}

Even if this runs at the backend, it's still takes a lot of time to run, and the system gives error below

```html
An exception of type 'Telerik.OpenAccess.Exceptions.DataStoreException' occurred in Telerik.OpenAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: System.ArgumentException: null oid not supported

   at Telerik.OpenAccess.SPI.Backends.ThrowException(Exception e)
```

Actually, even if backend graps the data successfully, it's impossible to pass through JSON. The data is huge. I came up with a way that generate the excel file at backend, then pass FileResult to frontend. Is there any better ideas?

```js
function gridExcel_Click() {

        var grid = $("#GridTruckSummary").data('kendoGrid');
        grid.saveAsExcel();
    }
```

```html
 .Excel(excel => excel
   .FileName("TruckSummary On"+ DateTime.Now +".xlsx")
   .Filterable(true)
   .AllPages(true)
  )
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Custom().Text("<span class=\"k-icon k-i-excel\"></span> Export to Excel").Url("javascript:gridExcel_Click()");
    })
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Passing the FileResult back to the frontend is what I had to do as well. I'd say that will be your best option with such a big dataset.

Comment: @Supersnake That's right. JSon is impossible to carry such a big dataset.